Injective PRG from one-way functions
I'm interested in exploring the construction of injective pseudorandom generators (PRGs), i.e., PRGs that are also 1-1 functions. We know that we can construct regular PRGs from one-way functions, as shown by Håstad et al.
While it is known that injective PRGs can be built from one-way permutations (as discussed in this post), one-way functions do not imply the existence of one-way permutations, as demonstrated by Rudich. This raises the question: are there any known constructions of injective PRGs that rely directly on one-way functions, without assuming the existence of one-way permutations?

There is no black-box construction of injective OWFs from OWFs. This is a folklore result that I don't think is formally stated anywhere, but follows from (the same analysis as) existing black-box separations between OWFs and OWPs. This is for example mentioned explicitly in a footnote on the first page of this paper, where it is credited as a result "implicit" in those three papers (I did not personally check whether it's true, but I believe the authors on this topic). It follows that there is no black-box construction of injective PRG from OWFs.
On the positive side, if you start from an exponentially secure OWF, then it's possible to construct (in a black-box way) an almost 1-1 family of OWFs, via the construction of this paper. It looks highly plausible to me that plugging this "almost 1-1 OWF family" into the construction of injective PRG from OWP would yield an "almost injective PRG family" (i.e., a family of PRGs where, with overwhelming probability over the sampling of a random PRG from the family, the sampled PRG is injective). I did, however, not thoroughly check this claim and one would have to carefully prove it, I don't think it has been formally proven anywhere.

Thanks a lot for your answer.

My pleasure. I edited the answer to add a positive result, in case this is also of interest for what you have in mind.

The positive result is intriguing. I'll definitely look into it, although my original focus was on starting from standard OWF.
